# How to calculate matrix product on (sparse) bit matrix efficiently in python

Tags: python, scipy, bit-manipulation, intel-mkl

Ordinary matrix product between bit array:

```
           1, 0, 0
Matrix A = 1, 1, 1
           0, 0, 1

                 1, 1, 0
Transpose of A = 0, 1, 0
                 0, 1, 1

C = Matrix A times (Transpose of Matrix A)

    1, 1, 0
C = 1, 3, 1
    0, 1, 1
```

A is a bit array of 1 and 0. The actual matrix A is large and has about 0.25% 1 entries and 99.75% zero entries.

C is an array of integer.

How to calculate this quickly without using lots of memory?

Currently, I am using scipy's sparse matrix multiplication routines for compressed sparse row matrices of floating point 1.0 and 0.0 in python. I am also trying to call c functions in mkl library directly to reduce memory usage.

Comment: How large? How long does it take for a 1000 x 1000 matrix?

Comment: it is to calculate product between a 750,000 x b matrix and its transpose. b is at least 10,000. The larger the b, the better. But memory per cpu core is limited.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a matrix A with a shape of b x 750,000. So the A times transpose of A should have a shape of b x b.

Comment: @rxu given 750000 and 0.25%, your C has 99% non-zero elements. You may want to store it in dense format.

Comment: that depends on if the b rows tends to have 1 at the same column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing performance libraries such as MKL always use float/double as the data type. Comparing to converting your A to a float CSR and then calling `.dot()` or some MKL routines, you may find writing your own `bit-mat-mul` code is faster. You don't even need the multiply operation. It is only counting the bits.

**Edit**

After knowing your context on the queation, I would suggest the following procedure.

1. Convert your array A to CSR format and store only col indices and row ptr;
2. For each row i and row j of A, count the number of  common col indices and store the result in C(i, j) with i<=j only as C is symmetric. This is fast if col indices are sorted.

The dense matric C is what you want.

Given the size (b x 750,000) and the density (0.25%) of your A, the density of C is 99.1%; the average length of each col indices is 1875.

So your problem becomes counting the number of common elements of 2 1875-D vectoers for `b*(b+1)/2` times.

The the speed of the for loop seems the only remaining problem.

Comment: Previous questions by @rxu imply the data may be stored as `gmpy2.mpz` type. If that's correct, `gmpy2.hamdist(row & col, 0)` should be very fast.

Comment: Let me try that. I worry the overhead python loop and calling c++ from python will make things slow... actually i wrote a version to use python's set and intersection once. That one is much slower than scipy's dot for sparse matrix. Even though constructing the sparse matrix takes time. The combined time is still much faster than the set version. In the previous part of the program I used mpz and python loop to calculate logical_and very quickly. That worked very well, and scipy can't do that fast and uses tons of memory.

Comment: At that first part of program work on dense bit array. Now I have to work with sparse array in the 2nd part of the program.

Comment: The set version uses lots of memory too. That makes b small.

Comment: Another thing is that I have to squeeze that b x 750,000 matrix into memory before calculating the product. sparse matrix beats dense matrix by a large margin in memory efficiency in my case.

Comment: not good... much slower than scipy and sparse matrices that way. probably the overhead is too much in the python double loop.

Comment: @rxu Then maybe you have to write a C++ function to do the whole thing. The overhead of calling it once should be the same as calling `.dot()`. When using `.dot()`, you are actually calling a C/C++ function that do the real work too.

Comment: I don't know if that performance slow down is mostly caused by the overhead, using a dense instead of sparse bit array, or both.

Comment: bit array would save some memory because I expected the 1 in each row would be close to each other. Denser regions of more 1 separated by many 0.

Comment: I guess I will try the mkl library for now because I have been working on that for 4 days. Thanks casevh and Eric for the suggestions.